# WPF ListView Update list items values after new item is added (values change with time)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have an app that responds to events and adds the data from the events to a "ListView", and I have a simple class that have 3 properties.

ListView holds this data:

```
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public TimeAgo Time { get; set; }
```

class TimeAgo is:

```
public class TimeAgo
{

    private DateTime _time;

    public TimeAgo(DateTime time) { _time = time; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - _time.Ticks).Seconds + " seconds ago";
    }
}
```

so, whenever a new event is happening I want the other objects to update, so if I add a new one it says "0 seconds ago" but the old ones should be updated and say "15 seconds ago" so I can track how long ago each event happened when it's updated.

I've searched for methods for this, but all I've tried haven't worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, any way to make the "last" item added appear above all others? So latest entry is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make Seconds a property you bind to.

To put at top

```
Insert(0, T item
```

For all the items in the ObservableCollection call NotifyPropertyChanged("Seconds"); after the insert.

Comment: I can't find any EventHandler for NotifyPropertyChanged on either ObservableCollection or the ListView.

Comment: You need to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged on the class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple task.
"latest entry is first" - you may simply order your DataSource by TimeAgo (but you'll have to implement IComparable)

Do you use MVVM (you tagged it as WPF)? If yes - just use ObservableCollection Class as ListView DataSourse. Also should investigate [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: To implement INotifyPropertyChanged you need to declare the PropertyChanged event and create the OnPropertyChanged method. Then for each property you want change notifications for, you call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated. Just call OnPropertyChanged in setter

Comment: I figured it out to just add Items.Insert(0, new Data());